# Put custom arrow on top of custom dropdown

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I've created following custom dropdown:
[image]

But as you can see, the arrow is not placed on top of the actual dropdown. I've been trying messing around with a lot of properties, but it seems I'm unable to get the arrow on top of the dropdown while also having the arrow position to absolute - and not having it set to absolute begins to seem really messy and imprecise.

```css
.custom-dropdown select {
  background-color: #f6c02a;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 385px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  text-overflow: '';
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* hide default arrow in chrome OSX */
}

.custom-dropdown::before,
.custom-dropdown::after {
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 170px;
}

.custom-dropdown::after {
  /*  Custom dropdown arrow */
  content: "\25BC";
}
```

```html
<div id="search1">
  <input type="text" id="searchplayer1" placeholder="Player1...">
  <br>
  <span class="custom-dropdown">
            <select>    
                <option value="SelectRegion">Select Region...</option>
                <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
                <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                <option value="North America">North America</option>
                <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
                <option value="Kakao">Kakao</option>
                <option value="South East Asia">South East Asia</option>
                <option value="South and Central America">South and Central America</option>
                <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
            </select>
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I would rather recommend you to use a Jquery plugin for dropdown, and customise it. Or you can create your own HTML dropdown by making use of `<ul>` and `<li>...` with any custom styling. and can write JS code to capture and handle click events.

Comment: You want to start by positioning your span container element relative, to set the reference point for its absolutely positioned ancestors. Then remove the padding from the pseudo element, and specify actual top/right values ...

Comment: @CBroe ah, silly - setting the span to relative seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, Using ::before element like this

```
.custom-dropdown::before {
  content: "\25BC";
}
```

```css
.custom-dropdown select {
  background-color: #f6c02a;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 385px;
  height: 30px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  text-overflow: '';
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* hide default arrow in chrome OSX */
}

.custom-dropdown::before,
.custom-dropdown::after {
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
      padding-left: 370px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.custom-dropdown::before {
  /*  Custom dropdown arrow */
  content: "\25BC";
}
```

```html
<div id="search1">
  <input type="text" id="searchplayer1" placeholder="Player1...">
  <br>
  <span class="custom-dropdown">
            <select>    
                <option value="SelectRegion">Select Region...</option>
                <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
                <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                <option value="North America">North America</option>
                <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
                <option value="Kakao">Kakao</option>
                <option value="South East Asia">South East Asia</option>
                <option value="South and Central America">South and Central America</option>
                <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
            </select>
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using left and top with absolute position

```css
    
  
 .custom-dropdown select {
      background-color: #f6c02a;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: inherit;
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
      width: 385px;
      height: 30px;
      text-indent: 5px;
      text-overflow: '';
      -webkit-appearance: button;
      /* hide default arrow in chrome OSX */
    }

    
 .custom-dropdown::before,
 .custom-dropdown::after {
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 370px;
  top: 35px;
}

    .custom-dropdown::after {
      /*  Custom dropdown arrow */
      content: "\25BC";
    }
```

```html
    <div id="search1">
      <input type="text" id="searchplayer1" placeholder="Player1...">
      <br>
      <span class="custom-dropdown">
                <select>    
                    <option value="SelectRegion">Select Region...</option>
                    <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
                    <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
                    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                    <option value="North America">North America</option>
                    <option value="Oceania">Oceania</option>
                    <option value="Kakao">Kakao</option>
                    <option value="South East Asia">South East Asia</option>
                    <option value="South and Central America">South and Central America</option>
                    <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                </select>
            </span>
    </div>
```